# User-defined table type with column Id as Identity(1,1)

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net, user-defined-types

I am using a user-defined table type as parameter in a procedure and that user defined table has a column `Id` which has the `identity` flag set.

Problem:

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[UdtTable] AS TABLE
                                (
                                    [Id] [INT] IDENTITY(1, 1),
                                    [StudentId] [INT] NOT NULL
                                )
```

When executing my procedure in SQL Server directly, it's working, but when I am calling this procedure from C# code, it's not working but it's also not showing any errors.

This query runs fine:

```
DECLARE @TableUDT [UdtTable];

INSERT INTO @TableUDT 
    SELECT 201;

INSERT INTO @TableUDT 
    SELECT 202;

EXEC MYProcName @TableUDT
```

But this isn't working:

```
DataTable udtDataTable = new DataTable();
udtDataTable.Columns.Add("StudentId");


DataRow dRow = udtDataTable.NewRow();
dRow["StudentId"] = 201
udtDataTable.Rows.Add(dRow)

DataRow dRow2 = udtDataTable.NewRow();
dRow2["StudentId"] = 201
udtDataTable.Rows.Add(dRow2)

List<SqlParameter> parameters = new List<SqlParameter>();
parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@TableLeaveID", udtDataTable));

DataTable = new DML.RunProcedure("MyProcName",parameters);
```

**Note**: according to my procedure it should return a table.

Comment: You need to call `udtDataTable.Rows.Add(dRow)` to actually **add** those news rows to the `DataTable`!! Right now, you're just creating two "free-floating" `DataRow` instances - but those aren't **added** to the `DataTable` !

Comment: Sorry! I have missed mentioning that line. I am already using udtDataTable.Rows.Add(dRow) to add.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 3 things that can be passed as a Table Value Parameter:

- IEnumerable
- DataTable
- DbDataReader

You can try to use `IEnumerable<SqlDataRecord>`

The keypoint is to use a [SqlMetaData](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sqlserver.server.sqlmetadata?view=netframework-4.8) constructor for that column that sets `useServerDefault` to `true` for `Id` parameter.

```
var sqlMetaData = new[] 
{  
  new SqlMetaData("Id", SqlDbType.Int, true, false, SortOrder.Unspecified, -1),   
  new SqlMetaData("StudentId", SqlDbType.Int)
};

var record = new SqlDataRecord(sqlMetaData);   
record.SetInt32(1, 201);   
List<SqlDataRecord> sqlRecords = new List<SqlDataRecord>();
sqlRecords.Add(record);

parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@TableLeaveID", sqlRecords));
```